# How presenter access value in a text box for validation

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, validation, mvp

I have following method in my presenters which validates the user inputs on the UI. Basically to capture the value of the text property of the text box, it uses sender object which was passed in by the event fire on the form.

**PRESENTER**

```
_View.ValidateInPut += new EventHandler(_View_ValidateInPut);

private void _View_ValidateInPut(object sender,  EventArgs e)
{
    var controller = (TextBox)sender;
    var text = controller.Text;

    If (text is InValid)
    MessageBox.Show ("The value in the Text box is invalid");

}
```

**VIEW**

```
private void txtACNo_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    ValidateInPut(sender, e); // Firing the event
}
```

Will this lead to unexpected errors?

If so please let me know a better way to do this?

**EDIT (for the sake of clarity) :**

This code compiles and runs without errors. Basically what I wanted to know is that, is this a standard way to do this? Have you done things before in this way? If its not good, let me know  a better way to do the same!

Comment: There was a mistake in code. I edited it.

Comment: _Will this lead to unexpected errors?_ please run the code and see! when this step is done, post a real question

Comment: @ chouaib, code compiles without errors!. My question was, would this approach be problematic in some unforeseen situations when work with different events;)

Comment: I can't understand when you want to make the validation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way you are coupling your **Presenter** with the Web Controls. If you decide to change the `TextBox` with another control that accepts input you will need to change code both in the **View** and in the **Presenter**. The **Presenter** should not be aware of the type of controls you are using in the **View**.

Here is what you can do to decouple the **Presenter** from the **View**.

You need to define an interface with properties you would need to get/set.

```
public interface IView
{
    string Input { get; }
}
```

Your solid implementation of the `IView` interface which can be an .aspx page, a .ascx user control etc. Needs to pass an instance of itself to the **Presenter**.
Lets say you have a `TextBox` somewhere in your markup. You return the `Text` property of the `TextBox` in the `Input` get accessor.

```
public class AspxPage : Page, IView
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Presenter presenter = new Presenter(this);
    }

    public string Input
    {
        get
        {
            return this.textBox.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Now in the **Presenter** you call the `Input` property of the `IView` interface which in the current case returns

```
public class Presenter
{
    private IView view;

    public Presenter(IView view)
    {
        this.view = view;
    }
    private void _ValidateInput()
    {
        string text = this.view.Input;

        If (text is InValid)
        MessageBox.Show ("The value in the Text box is invalid");

    }
}
```

What you gain by doing this is changing what type of control you use to design your **View** does not result in changes to the **Presenter**. For instance you can use the same presenter class for a web forms and win forms projects without worrying about the controls that you use as the **Presenter** is only aware of the **View** interface not the solid implementations.

You can look at a more detailed example here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14642/Model-View-Presenter-with-ASP-NET

Comment: First I'm not developing a web application. Anyway this post was helpful. But I have a problem. Lets say we have an Int not string. Then how do you going to validate it? Because we have to address some conversions inside the property to expose value as an Int!

Comment: The view interface holds the value of the text box. If this value is a valid number is up for the presenter to decide. This means you should parse the value of the text box in the presenter.

Comment: Ok if I encapsulate text property in the view... `Public int ID {get{return convert.ToInt(txtID.text)}` then the presenter can do the validation. But what happen if the user enters characters in the text box. An Exception will occur in the view. So don't we have to do a validation in the view too to over come this?

Comment: Exactly, if you parse the value in the view you will need to validate it once in the view and then in the presenter. This is why it is better to pass the string value to the presenter. This way all your validation will be in 1 place.